# A plain HTML Submit button passes to the controller only after the second click

Tags: html, spring-mvc

I have many submit buttons in my plain HTML . The one not working is as below:- the other are as same as below

```
< form:submit cssClass="action-button" name="excelBTNX" value="Excel" id="excelBTNX"  />
```

The function of the above button in the controller is to create a excel sheet and put in session(I can download it from cookies ) and returns back .

The defination of the corrosponding method in Controller is as same as for other buttons which are working fine .

The problem with this is ,it works only at even count hit .When I click for the first time the page gets refreshed . When I click for the second time , control passes to the controller and my excel comes up as cookies.

I tried to track whether the submit is working or not with javaScript code as

```
     $(‘form’).submit(function(){
     alert("event getting fired");
});
```

and it gives the alert for both the cases.

I have done the validation part from the controller(manually), so local inbuilt validators are not used . So I believe they are not the case.

How do I fix it ?

Controller codes:-

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "execute.action", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "excelBTNX")
public String excelOut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @ModelAttribute("mymodel") myModel model, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap modelmap) {

    scr14(request).initializeSomeCalculation(model);// some innercalss called to manupulate model
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if(1=1){//CRUD condition here true in READ mode.
        model= new myModel ();
    }


    byte[] excel = createExcelS14(model,request);
    String fileName = getExcelName() + ".xls";
    String filepath = myFrameWorkUtils.createTempFile(excel, fileName);
    if (session != null) {
        session.setAttribute(fileDownload, filepath);
    }
  scr14(request).initializeSomeCalculation(model);
    model.setDate(somedate);
    return "myPanel";}
```

Comment: I would first see whether this issue is related to your Excel processing or whether it is something with your Controller. 

Just comment out the Excel functionality in the Controller and just forward to a new page if the Controller method for the button is 
Please post the Controller code the is invoked with your button.

Comment: Ok ! I will try commenting the codes @MarcFasel , and post my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some steps:

- Check whether this issue is related to your Excel processing or whether it is something with your Controller. I assume you have something like

> ```
> @RequestMapping(..., params = "excelBTNX")
> public ModelAndView next(...) 
> { <EXCEL FUNCTIONALITY> }
> ```

Just comment out the  in the Controller and verify that the method is called every time. Please test this a **let us know whether this is working**.

- What happens that makes you think the Controller is only called at the second click? Maybe the signs that you are looking at don't really mean that the controller is only called every second click. **Please explain**.
- Fix `if (1=1)` code. `=` in Java is the assignment operator, `==` is the comparison operator. I assume you want to do a comparison. It also seems like you simplified this part of the code, but it may actually be the problem. **Please post the actual code here**.
- I don't see anything about cookies here. It looks to me like you are creating a temporary Excel file, and setting the name of the file in the session.

`session.setAttribute(fileDownload, filepath)` cannot work, since the key of the session attribute map is of type String. It should probably be `session.setAttribute("fileDownload", filepath)`.

- Can you see whether there is a new temp Excel file generated with each click? You should be able to tell by the timestamp.

This may still not point to the problem, but it will certainly get us closer.

Comment: You r right about the model defination and the implementation. I need excel in cookies because I modify my model in controller and use the data of the model to create excel sheet . I have edited the Question with controller codes.

Comment: Yes! You are right about almost everything in your answer !Thanks . I am much sure the control is not passing to the controller : by debugging the code and commenting it. And  no excel is being created for the first click , I checked it by the timestamp. I have come up to a hint by now :- The button gets  focus at first click and works from the second .just a wild guess.

Comment: If your JavaScript code fires every time then your Controller method should be called every time. It is also odd that other buttons work fine, but this one behaves differently. I would try to isolate now if this is a front-end/ JavaScript issue or a back-end/Spring-MVC issue that there is a discrepancy between the registered clicks in the front-end and the calls to the controller. Good luck!

Comment: @Narayan Can you please verify whether this is the solution and accept answer if that is the case? thx.

Comment: The isolation of the problem from JavaScript spring MVC has extended itslef to HTML.Let me state some of my test here                                                              1> I removed all the screens other components except Submit buttons . the button worked fine . I checked the html it seems ok .          2> reverted the changes of 1 . The code is not going to the controller 3> created another hidden submit button and redirected the its click() function with the click event of excelBTN in java script , still the page gets to the controller only once . Checked it with the debugger .

Comment: Seriously thank you for your support ! I will comment when I get the answer(may be  have done some silly mistake around ). but the simple question that pops up in my mind is why java script click function gets me an alert(""), but not get submitted into the controller.

Comment: And I have lots of lostFocus /click/change/getScript /post function of the screen components . I also have a doubt on these.

Comment: Well I found the problem . The problem was I had many comboBox at my screen . The control at the first click() of excelBTN was going to a method in controller. where the param was a combo's name . My be combo box are intended to submit them-self every Time, if they have drop down values . The 2nd time the button worked was because ,combo had no values at that time(since the page just refreshed without loading the combox boxes). And the other buttons wore working fine because all those methods wore above the comboBox controller methods. Thanks.